# How to run a WebSocket server in Java EE 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-7, java-websocket

I am new to Java EE and trying to build a WebSocket server. So far I have the following class:

```
import java.io.IOException;


import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

/** 
 * @ServerEndpoint gives the relative name for the end point
 * This will be accessed via ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo
 * Where "localhost" is the address of the host,
 * "EchoChamber" is the name of the package
 * and "echo" is the address to access this class from the server
 */
@ServerEndpoint("/echo") 
public class EchoServer {
    /**
     * @OnOpen allows us to intercept the creation of a new session.
     * The session class allows us to send data to the user.
     * In the method onOpen, we'll let the user know that the handshake was 
     * successful.
     */
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session){
        System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection"); 
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * When a user sends a message to the server, this method will intercept the message
     * and allow us to react to it. For now the message is read as a String.
     */
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session){
        System.out.println("Message from " + session.getId() + ": " + message);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The user closes the connection.
     * 
     * Note: you can't send messages to the client from this method
     */
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session){
        System.out.println("Session " +session.getId()+" has ended");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

I cannot figure out nor can I find any examples showing me how to run this server. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need a container, such as WildFly or GlassFish.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin do you have any examples of how to use these containers for this purpose?

Comment: @kg that's the subject of entire books, not for a simple example. JavaEE development is not something you just roll into. Start by reading the official material (google: javaee 7 websockets, [result](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm) ) and you'll figure out what you need to research more going from there.

Comment: check [this example](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/maven-websocketapi.html)